# How to use java-object-diff library to compare object graph involving one-to-many relationships implemented using lists?

Tags: java, object, graph, compare

I want to compare 'working' and 'base' copies of complex object graphs involving various collections and create a change log. From stackoverflow, I noticed that java-object-diff library (https://github.com/SQiShER/java-object-diff) can work for me. I have skimmed through available documentation/examples, but I am not still clear about:

1. How it compares collections?
2. Is order of items in the collection relevant?
3. How it can be configured to use 'equals' methods instead of introspection?

For example, if I have a 'User' and 'Role' objects. A User can have many Roles. Both override 'equals' method using their identifiers. How can I compare different copies of users with their respective roles?

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

1. Collections are compared by using the equals and hashCode methods of its items. Each item will be represented by a so called `DiffNode` and either marked as `UNTOUCHED`, `ADDED`, `REMOVED` or `CHANGED`. If an item (with the same identity) is found in base and working it will be checked for changes and either be marked as `UNTOUCHED` or `CHANGED`. Otherwise it will be marked as `ADDED` or `REMOVED` respectively. One feature that the library is still lacking is support for ordering and multiple occurences of items in a Collection. It will basically treat all collection types as `Set` and simply check for presence of an object. As long as you don't care about the order or need to put an item several times into the same collection, that shouldn't be a problem.
2. Not yet. But an advanced ListDiffer is certainly possible and is something I've been dreaming of for while. It's just a pretty complex topic and I didn't get to it yet.
3. There are several ways: you can annotate your type with `@ObjectDiffEqualsOnlyType` or your property getter with `@ObjectDiffProperty(equalsOnly=true)`. If you cannot use annotations, you can also do it programatically by using the methods `withEqualsOnlyType(final Class<?> type)` or `withEqualsOnlyProperty(final PropertyPath propertyPath)` of the `Configuration`. The upcoming version will come with a fluent configuration API to make this kind of configuration easier and more powerful.

Regarding your example: given that you pass two versions of the `User` to the `ObjectDiffer`, java-object-diff would return a node (root node), representing the `User`. As long as you don't mark the User class as equals-only-type, it would simply be compared on a per-property basis. Each property would end up as a child of the root node. Now let's say one of the properties is a `List` of Roles: the library will group the items that exist in the base and working version (known items), those that only exist in the base version (removed) and those that only exist in the working version (added). This either happens by using the `contains` methods of the underlying collections or by comparing the items directly via `equals`. "Known" items will then be checked for changes. This could be a simple call to `equals` or a deep comparison via introspection; depending on the way it is configured for the given type.